# reactjs - how to set inline style of backgroundcolor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set the style properties of some elements but I don't have the syntax correct.  Can anyone suggest where I am wrong?

```
import React from 'react';
import debug from 'debug'

const log = debug('app:component:Header');

var bgColors = { "Default": "#81b71a",
                    "Blue": "#00B1E1",
                    "Cyan": "#37BC9B",
                    "Green": "#8CC152",
                    "Red": "#E9573F",
                    "Yellow": "#F6BB42",
};

export default class SideBar extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }


  render() {

    return (


    <a style="{{backgroundColor: {bgColors.Default}}}" >default</a>
    <a style="{{backgroundColor: {bgColors.Blue}}}" >blue</a>
    <a style="{{backgroundColor: {bgColors.Cyan}}}" >cyan</a>
    <a style="{{backgroundColor: {bgColors.Green}}}" >green</a>
    <a style="{{backgroundColor: {bgColors.Red}}}"  >red</a>
    <a style="{{backgroundColor: {bgColors.Yellow}}}" >yellow</a>
           );
  }

}
```

UPDATE: for anyone looking at this please see comments this is not working code.

Comment: Also does this work? I would how thought you would have to wrap those anchor in a single element as the return is supposed to be one element, not many -- unless you redacted something

Comment: It probably doesn't work.  I hacked it down from a much larger piece of code.

Comment: This is the correct syntax: `<p style= {{color:'gray'}}>{props.item.text}</p>`

Answer (score 91, accepted):

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html

You don't need the quotes.

```
<a style={{backgroundColor: bgColors.Yellow}}>yellow</a>
```

Comment: I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: bgColors is not defined` error when I use it in my react view component. Am I missing something?

Comment: That link redirects to https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html. Also, I don't like this documentation on React style tags because it simply tells you `The style attribute accepts a JavaScript object with camelCased properties rather than a CSS string`. Does it accept all CSS styles? Transitions included? A list of the proper React style properties would be nice.

Answer (score 27):

Your quotes are in the wrong spot.  Here's a simple example:

```
<div style={{backgroundColor: "#FF0000"}}>red</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want more than one style this is the correct full answer.
This is div with class and style:

```
<div className="class-example" style={{width: '300px', height: '150px'}}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <a style={{ backgroundColor: bgColors.Default }}>default</a>
```